# Silverman's AEC prop 1.4 uniformizer

Tags: elliptic-curves, valuation-theory

Regarding Silverman's AEC, page $19$, Proposition $1.4$

> each of the terms in the sum has distinct order at P, so every term
> must vanish

But why? I guess we need to show order of curve satisfies the axiom of valuation beforehand.
I cannot find any contradiction with $\Phi(t,x)=0$, any help (hints) would be appreciated!

Comment: Since some people might not have Silverman's AEC, your question would be improved by adding details which make it understandable independent of your citation.

Comment: If you add up a bunch of terms of distinct degree, they can't cancel to give you zero, but that sum is zero. Question aside, I'd recommend skipping chapters 1 and 2 except maybe for a brief skim, and just refer to them as necessary starting at chapter 3.

Comment: Thank you for your good comment! But why can we  replace ’order' with 'degree'? I'm wondering why the sum of terms of distinct order cannot be zero.And  is  it correct to understand that we can conclude that all terms are zero because we got a contradiction assuming some term is not zero ?